# How to check how many seconds are left for the current session?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

`Session.Timeout` only returns the static value in `Web.Config`. But I want to get a value of how many seconds are left till the current session expires. What should I do?

---

I tried to retrieve the `Session.Timeout` from JavaScript.

```
setInterval('checkSession()', 100);
```

And the `checkSession()` is:

```
function checkSession() {
    console.log('Timeout: <%= Session.Timeout %>');
}
```

The page spit out the current `Session.Timeout` value for several minutes and it only proves that `Session.Timeout` is the static value set in my `Web.Config`, not a dynamic value which shows me how many minutes are left.

Comment: If your code is invoked as a result of a request, then the session timeout is being reset with the request.

Comment: `<%= Session.Timeout %>` is a one-time evaluation that occurs only once, on page load, it will not change until the next page load

Answer (score 2):

I think, it only makes sense, if you do this control on client side like the most online bank sites.

```
<script>
   var timeLeft = <%= Session.Timeout * 60 %>; // seconds
   self.setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
   function checkTime()
   {
       timeLeft--;
       if (timeLeft < 120) // 2 minutes left
       {
         alert("2 minutes left.");
         // well you can refresh or close the page
         document.frames["iframeSession"].location.reload();
       }
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Then the next question is how I can extend the session after the warning.

Comment: @Blaise - not that you should, but you can modify the section above and instead of an `alert`, refresh the page, send user somewhere else, etc. - basically as in some of the comments have already mentioned, induce the client to make another request (to same web app of course).

Comment: @Blaise - I personally use a hidden iframe to do that instead of refreshing a whole page. Added to answer.

Comment: Does it mean as long as there is a page load, a call to a server resource, the timeout will be extended to another 20 minutes (let's say we are using the default timeout value)?

Comment: yes. every call to the application resets the time even the AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that on the server (which doesn't make much sense) it is equal to `Session.Timeout` since you are actively processing a request within session.

To do it on the client side, you simply pass `Session.Timeout` value to the page and work with it using javascript (record the time when page was rendered and compare current time to it).

Comment: But how can I add a few more minutes to that Session?

Comment: Can you please give some detail on how to "triggering a new request"?

Comment: You can refresh the page (`window.location.href = window.location.href`) or just trigger an ajax request to foo.aspx or something..